# Can you have a multi-line comment a crontab

Tags: linux, cron

Can I use the C++/Java-style `/* */` syntax to multi-line comments in the crontab file?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The only comment character allowed in a crontab file is `#`. So you need to do:

```
# This is line 1
# This is line 2
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/magiccronjob
```

Edit: I believe it's [man 5 crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) to see the details about crontab syntax.

Comment: "Blank lines and leading spaces and tabs are ignored. Lines whose first non-space character is a pound-sign (#) are comments, and are ignored. Note that comments are not allowed on the same line as cron commands, since they will be taken to be part of the command. Similarly, comments are not allowed on the same line as environment variable settings."

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/749963